# How to subscribe set event after async from interop dll

Tags: c#, event-handling, interop, dllimport

I want to subscribe event from `hEvent`, but still dont understand how to subcribe from `IntPtr`. I searched on web to find tht the way is to use  a delegate. How to subscribe event of such property?

My C# code :

```
var hEvent = new IntPtr();
IntPtr lpcOmcr = OMCR_OpenDevice(null, ref lpcOption);
uint result = OMCR_TurnonLED(lpcOmcr, (int)ReturnCode.LedColor.OMCR_SET_LED_COLOR_GREEN, ref hEvent); //result = 1 == OMCR_STATUS_PENDING
```

API Documentation :
[image]

Does anyone ever experienced this? Thank you.
Note : This code works to turn on LED.

Answer (score 0):

The "event" in this case is not the same as a C# event. It's an unmanaged Windows event handle. All you can do is wait on it. Fortunately, .NET does provide some useful wrappers to let you use one.

The basic way you would handle this is like this:

```
var hEvent = new IntPtr();
IntPtr lpcOmcr = OMCR_OpenDevice(null, ref lpcOption);
uint result = OMCR_TurnonLED(lpcOmcr, (int)ReturnCode.LedColor.OMCR_SET_LED_COLOR_GREEN, ref hEvent); //result = 1 == OMCR_STATUS_PENDING

using (EventWaitHandle waitEvent =
    new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset))
{
    waitEvent.SafeWaitHandle = new SafeWaitHandle(hEvent, false);
    waitEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

At least, that should work. Without a complete code example to start with, I can't test the above to make sure it works in your case.

Note that the above is strictly synchronous and of course does not involve a C# event at all. But you can of course take the above basic technique and wrap it in the desired C# abstractions.

Comment: in the example, i wait until i set `waitEvent.Set()` and in `waitEvent.SafeWaitHandle = new SafeWaitHandle(hEvent, false);` i just set existing handle to wait, how do i get signal from there? (on c# just subscribe with `+=`) I find references about this from web is very difficult :( @Peter Duniho

Comment: @yovierayz: as I said, the "event" here _has nothing to do with C#'s events_. For this question, you should just completely forget everything you know about C# events, including the `+=` subscription syntax. It's completely inapplicable to this scenario. All I've shown above is the minimum you need in order to respond/react to the library's returned event handle. You "get signal" by calling `WaitOne()`, as shown. It is possible to wrap the event handle in a C# event, but do you really need to? How long do you expect to wait for the event handle to be signaled?

Comment: Oh ok i understand. I need to run method after i get signal from event. On method to turn on led, i don't need it, but for other method. For example to detect the card when inserted. On the method `OMCR_MonitorCardStatus`, there is an event like that too. @Peter Duniho

Comment: @yovierayz: without more specifics, I can't say exactly what you should do. But one possibility would be to dedicate a thread to waiting on that event handle, or if you have other events as well, an array of event handlers. See e.g. [`WaitAny()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdykks7z(v=vs.110).aspx). Note that you can create your own `EventWaitHandle`, to signal such a thread in case you e.g. need to change the handles it's waiting on.